# How do i perform a meta-analysis of prevalence rates using metafor package (with no treatment group)?

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor, prevalence

I have a spreadsheet with this type of information:

```
city            cases      population      prevalence (per 100.000)       lower_CI      upper_CI

chicago          20          10000                200             
são paulo
berlin
```

I don't know what to do first with it, i tried to aplly to the forest function but it didn't work. I would like what to do first, according to my references i consider my data in a poisson-normal distributed model.

Comment: What question are you trying to answer? Do you assume all cities have the same underlying rate that you want to estimate?

Comment: Telling us it did not work is not very helpful. What did you do and what error message did you receive?